# Telegraph - не работает getViews

Tags: python, telegram

Пытаюсь сделать "чекер" статей по списку (txt с ссылками на статьи).
Хочу посчитать суммарно все просмотры на всех статьях в txt (ссылки).

Для начала решил воспользоваться getViews, но получаю ошибку снова и снова.

```
from telegraph import Telegraph
    
telegraph = Telegraph()
    
response = telegraph.get_views('https://api.telegra.ph/getViews/testfhiasehilf?year=2023&month=7')
    #https://telegra.ph/testfhiasehilf-07-21

print(response)
```

Пользовался мануалом https://telegra.ph/api#getViews